# Manipulating the placements of items in CSV files with R

Tags: r

I have a bit of code that makes linear regression models within a for loop from which I outputted the coefficients to CSV file,and then I sorted the data to columns to make it more readable. But when the data is sorted, I noticed that I would need to push the data in the first row to start in the second column. Here's the part of the code that matters:

```
for(i in 1:9152){
.
.

  modelCoeffs <- modelSummary$coefficients  # model coefficients
  write.table(featureID,"results.csv",append=T,sep=",")
  write.table(modelCoeffs,"results.csv",append=T,sep=",")
}
```

So how could I get the "modelCoeffs" row to start in the spot where second column starts?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but if the problem is that the first (index) column name is missing, you could use `write.csv` instead of `write.table` to solve it.

Comment: The problem is that I need to move the first row of model coeffs one column to the left, but keep the rest of the rows as is.

Comment: You could try adding a column of `NA` values and using `na = ""` in your `write.table` or `write.csv` call. An alternative could be to `rbind` your `featureID` and `modelCoeffs` together.